# Can you perform math functions inside of a PHP if statement?

Tags: php, forms, math

I am currently trying to create a "quiz" using a PHP form that will tell the user how similar their answers are to another user's. My first step is trying to display if the answer is the same as an answer that I  have already set. 
**My questions is if there is a way to perform math inside of an if statement? Or do I have to redefine the variable?**

```
$color = $_POST['color'];

$score = 0;

if ($color=='lime'){
    $score + 1;
}

echo "You had $score answers matching the computer."
```

Comment: What kind of maths?

Comment: You can perform calculation under and you are already doing it so whats the problem ?

Comment: Of course you can "perform math in an if statement". Guess: `$score + 1` **doesn't save the result anywhere.** You want `$scope = $score + 1`, or `$score += 1`.

Comment: you can use ++$score if the score only needs to increase by 1 or use $score += 2 for more than one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$score + 1;` is a perfectly valid statement... but it immediately discards the result.

```
++$score;
```

or

```
$score = $score + 1;
```

or

```
$score += 1;
```